# What is the "Views" referring to in: Completed 200 OK in 989ms (Views: 968.5ms | ActiveRecord: 13.9ms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an action that looks like this:

```
  def facebook_login    
     render json: {users:User.all}
  end
```

My local server running on a MacBook Pro Early 2013 outputs this:

> Completed 200 OK in 989ms (Views: 968.5ms | ActiveRecord: 13.9ms)

Heroku outputs this for the same API call:

> Completed 200 OK in 3849ms (Views: 3782.6ms | ActiveRecord: 49.4ms)

The Users table contains 3000 records.

This is the schema of the users table:

```
 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "email"
    t.string  "first_name"
    t.string  "last_name"
    t.string  "gender"
    t.string  "birthday"
    t.string  "bio"
    t.string  "facebook_id"
    t.string  "avatar"
    t.string  "password_digest"
    t.string  "auth_token"
    t.boolean "admin",           default: false, null: false
  end
```

My log from the rails server:

```
Started POST "/facebook_login.json" for 192.168.1.7 at 2015-07-06 03:39:07 -0400
Cannot render console from 192.168.1.7! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by HomeController#facebook_login as JSON
  Parameters: {"avatar"=>"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/10891984_10100428479784882_2780393036688516385_n.jpg?oh=b745f67a9aa8f12eeb283962473bade0&oe=5621674B&__gda__=1444484154_c3db5d55964941a930530b70aa6ef44c", "first_name"=>"Tara", "bio"=>"", "last_name"=>"Lloyd", "birthday"=>"07/08/1985", "email"=>"tlloyd07@gmail.com", "facebook_id"=>"10100528233672292", "auth_token"=>"750435390234913", "home"=>{"avatar"=>"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/10891984_10100428479784882_2780393036688516385_n.jpg?oh=b745f67a9aa8f12eeb283962473bade0&oe=5621674B&__gda__=1444484154_c3db5d55964941a930530b70aa6ef44c", "first_name"=>"Tara", "bio"=>"", "last_name"=>"Lloyd", "birthday"=>"07/08/1985", "email"=>"tlloyd07@gmail.com", "facebook_id"=>"10100528233672292", "auth_token"=>"750435390234913"}}
  User Load (13.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
Completed 200 OK in 989ms (Views: 968.5ms | ActiveRecord: 13.9ms)
```

I'm building a Rails App that pulls data from a database and returns a json. There are no images or views to be rendered. Why is the "Views" above almost one second (4 seconds on Heroku) while the ActiveRecord is only 14ms? What is this "Views" doing? All this API call is reading back 3000 records from the Users table, so why is so much time being spent on "Views"? Am I missing something?

I tried doing config.cache_classes = true in my environments/development.rb but it didn't change anything.

Also, I don't understand why I've been given six points off for this question. Did I offend anyone but insinuating that Rails is slow?

**EDIT:**

After replacing

> render json: {users:User.all}

with:

> render json: MultiJson.dump({users:User.all})

I see this in the Heroku logs:

```
Completed 200 OK in 5223ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 57.6ms)
```

However, 0.3ms + 57.5ms does NOT equal 5223ms, so what are those other five seconds spent on?

Comment: Based on _your_ code, you can never assert that something is slow.

Comment: I've expanded the question quite a bit, please take a look

Comment: Moderators, please reopen the question or I will delete it and ask again

Comment: I also am puzzled on why this is moderated down. Seems like a legit question to me.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of work and investigation, I've learned that rendering json in Rails is always going to be much slower than doing it in the database. Thus the solution is to bypass ActiveRecord and write direct SQL queries to Postgres:

```
res = []
res << ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select listings from listings;")
res << ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select users from users;")
render json: MultiJson.dump(res)
```

Following this I am seeing a 10x improvement in performance and speed:

```
Started GET "/listings.json?data=(%0A%20%20%20%20settings,%0A%20%20%20%20listings,%0A%20%20%20%20users%0A)" for 192.168.1.7 at 2015-07-07 00:27:33 -0400
Processing by HomeController#listings as JSON
  Parameters: {"data"=>"(\n    settings,\n    listings,\n    users\n)", "home"=>{}}
   (24.4ms)  select listings from listings;
   (9.3ms)  select users from users;
Completed 200 OK in 200ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 33.7ms)
```